# How can I add an entire static website?

Tags: magento-1.9, websites

I've made an static website with html and php, so I have my src folder with .html files, and folders img, css, fonts, img and js. How can I upload the entire folder to Magento. Like, I have my website with my products and stuff, and I want a link to this new website I made but it has to be in Magento, so my new website has all of the menus, footer, etc. of the "real" web.

I don't know if I'm explaining correctly, hope I do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar like this before. There are various roads you can take on this one:

- Just put your site in another folder in your Magento root and serve it from there. Your server will just host them (or you might have to add an exception rule to your `.htaccess` / nginx configuration). Drawback is that you will manually have to keep your menu and footer in sync with the real site. Or:
- Create a module with a frontend page and load your entire site using the layout XML of Magento inside the content block. Also include your JavaScript and CSS using the layout XML. This way the menu and footer are just like Magento and sessions are maintained. Drawback is that your stylesheets and/or JavaScript might collide with each other.
- Go for a hybrid approach (I did this once), where your static site includes the header and footer HTML from Magento, and style them in your static site to have as much as a seamingless experience (don't know about session cookies though...).
- Go IFrame on this one, but that brings it's own problems with it and might be a bitch to setup with responsiveness and stuff. Might require a lot of JavaScript magic.

So as you can see there is no 'simple' drop-it-and-you're-done approach for this, but perhaps these suggestions can help you in finding your proper solution.

Comment: I'm going to try this:  http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/using-magento-header-footer-outside-of-magento/

Comment: Hello, I'm interested on this:

"Go for a hybrid approach (I did this once), where your static site includes the header and footer HTML from Magento, and style them in your static site to have as much as a seamingless experience (don't know about session cookies though...)."

What's the code I have to use to include the header and footer? Thanks

Comment: What I did: I created 2 very basic Magento templates that rendered only the HTML of the header and the footer, and I used curl to include them in the static site (the static site was on a different domain/server). If you're on the same server there are probably easier ways, although nothing stops you from sending a curl request to your own server ;-)

Comment: I found another solution via iframes, thank you for your help! I would love to publish how I did it and post another question I have, but I need +5 reputation, so if you could upvote this question, I would appreciate it so much because it would give me 5 rep!

Comment: (+5 reputation so I can upload more than 2 links)